# Receive UDP data from specific port outputted to richtextbox while keeping text c#

Tags: c#, networking, udp, chat, packet-capture

I'm currently making a chat which is a direct UDP connection. I saw many suggestions of TCP chat and a third computer (server), but I didn't want that.
The chat should only work locally, as I've tested and are great on big places like school, work or other.

So far, I've gotten it to send UDP packet when hitting Return in textbox, but the person I'm sending it to, doesn't seam to get it into the program.
I'm using Wireshark, to check if it really goes to him, and it does.
I've tried several google searches and tests, but only seam to get errors, or don't get anything to the program.

What I want, is a translator which receives the UDP packet from specific port, and only shows the text-data from the packet. I want it displayed to a richTextBox2 pluss keeping what's already there.

Here's the code, and a few screenshots:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace chat
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {



    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        // set this.FormBorderStyle to None here if needed
        // if set to none, make sure you have a way to close the form!
    }


    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
            m.Result = (IntPtr)(HT_CAPTION);
    }

    private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
    private const int HT_CLIENT = 0x1;
    private const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
        pictureBox1.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
        this.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            {
                Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,
    ProtocolType.Udp);

                string IpAddress = textBox3.Text;
                IPAddress serverAddr = IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress);


                IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverAddr, 2522);

                string text = textBox4.Text + ": " + richTextBox1.Text;
                byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

                sock.SendTo(send_buffer, endPoint);

                richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + textBox4.Text + ": " + richTextBox1.Text;

                richTextBox1.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

screenshots:

[computer1 program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXSnc.png)

[computer2 Wireshark -test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Imf.png)

I've recently jumped from Visual Basic to C#, and I'm kind of new to network stuff.
Thanks a lot if you are willing to help :)

Comment: You socket close immediately after data is sent becuase the socket is declared in the KeyDown method.  Not a very good idea because the socket could close before the data is actually received.  the socket will be disposed when you return from the KeyDown method.

Comment: well, Wireshark shows it all, and there is no problem sending it what so ever

Comment: When does the close occur?  Unless you see the message actually get received doesn't mean the message actually got to the receiver.  The close actually can get to the receiver before the last message.

Comment: so you suggest I get it running all the time? so that it receives and sends better?

Comment: Open the connection in the Form Load and keep it open until application closes.  This way you can receive as well as send.  How can you receive when you are closing the connection after you send?

Comment: I can't figure it out. How do I keep it open? should I move the whole code over to Form1_Load?

Comment: Looks like you solve issue yourself.  Programming errors often occur due to the scope of variables.  Putting UdpClient inside a method created issues.  Defining UdpClient in global space was part of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working.

here's the code so far, and it works!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace chat
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form

  {



    private const int MyPort = 2522;
    private UdpClient Client;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create the UdpClient and start listening.
        Client = new UdpClient(MyPort);
        Client.BeginReceive(DataReceived, null);
    }

    private void DataReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, MyPort);
        byte[] data;
        try
        {
            data = Client.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);

            if (data.Length == 0)
                return; // No more to receive
            Client.BeginReceive(DataReceived, null);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            return; // Connection closed
        }

        // Send the data to the UI thread
        this.BeginInvoke((Action<IPEndPoint, string>)DataReceivedUI, ip, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
    }

    private void DataReceivedUI(IPEndPoint endPoint, string data)
    {
        richTextBox2.AppendText(data + Environment.NewLine);
        label4.Text = ("[" + endPoint.ToString() + "]");
        //richTextBox2.AppendText("[" + endPoint.ToString() + "] " + data + Environment.NewLine);
    }



    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
            m.Result = (IntPtr)(HT_CAPTION);
    }

    private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
    private const int HT_CLIENT = 0x1;
    private const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
        pictureBox1.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
        this.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            {
                Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

                string IpAddress = textBox3.Text;
                IPAddress serverAddr = IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress);


                IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverAddr, 2522);

                string text = textBox4.Text + ": " + richTextBox1.Text;
                byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

                sock.SendTo(send_buffer, endPoint);

                richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox2.Text + textBox4.Text + ": " + richTextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine;

                richTextBox1.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var addr in Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList)
        {
            if (addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                label5.Text = "" + addr;
        }
    }

  }
}
```

In case you were making something simular, this code only works on local internet

Comment: This code will work over internet provided the IP address can be reached.  There is no restrictions in this code that limits to only a local internet.

Comment: I know, and this code is meant for large buildings like school, work or other large places.
If I where to extend this over the whole world, I guess I would iether, port forward or do something crazy with this code